# Emacs: select a region and type to delete the region

Tags: emacs

How can I tell emacs to work in the same way as Windows or Mac where if I select a region, and start typing, the region will be deleted prior to the new text to be inserted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think it does it out of the box, it looks like you have to turn on delete-selection-mode as per [this article on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode).

So, basically put the following line into your .emacs:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```

Comment: And consider sending an enhancement request to Emacs to ask that `delete-selection-mode` be turned on by default: `M-x report-emacs-bug` (it's also for enhancement requests).  It took a couple of decades to finally get selection highlighting (so-called `transient-mark-mode`) to be turned on by default --- progress is slow and regular-user input can help.

Comment: As an alternative to editing your **.emacs** file directly, you can change the setting of interest interactively using the [Customize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving) user interface: `M-x customize-variable [RET] delete-selection-mode [RET]`.